# How do I pass props down from react-router-doms's render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am aware that to pass down props to my Routes I need to use the render. For example:

```
const BaseRouter = (props) => (

    <div>
        {console.log(props)} // this displays everything I need, including props.username
        <Route exact path='/room/' render={(props) => <Room {...props} />} />
    </div>
);
```

The problem is that inside my Room component, the only props passed down are history, location, and match (these come straight from react-router-dom).

I have also tried manually passing the props needed down:

```
<Route exact path='/room/' render={(props) => <Room {...props} username={props.username} />} />
```

But inside Room, I still get undefined for props.username. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give a different name to you variables. Doing `render={(props) => <Room {...props} />` will always pass the router props, that is why `props.username` is undefined.

```
const BaseRouter = (props) => (

    <div>
        <Route exact path='/room/' render={(routeProps) => <Room {...routeProps} {...props} />} />
    </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Route component takes children as well.

```js
const BaseRouter = (props) => (

    <div>
        {console.log(props)} // this displays everything I need, including props.username
        <Route exact path='/room/'>
          <Room {...props}/>
        </Route>
    </div>
);
```

In *Room* component you can use useHistory, useLocation and useRouteMatch hooks. If *Room* is class based component then withRouter HOC is also useful.